NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long SecuGen.Driver.SmartCapture3Fdu05.Start(int, boolean)' on a null object reference
I developed an application for **android **where i am getting Finger Print using **SecuGen **Pro 20 device.
Samsung device capture the finger print image. But other device can not capture image (such as: One plus, Redmi, Xiaomi, Techno etc. device)
Initialization part into onCreate() section
//  fingerPrintEnable()
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        requireContext(),
        0,
        Intent(Const.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    filter = IntentFilter(Const.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
    // registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter)
    jsgfpLib = JSGFPLib(requireContext().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager)
    bSecuGenDeviceOpened = false
    usbPermissionRequested = false
    autoOn = SGAutoOnEventNotifier(jsgfpLib, this)

Image capture code
mRegisterImage = ByteArray(mImageWidth * mImageHeight)
        var result = jsgfpLib.GetImage(mRegisterImage)
        result = jsgfpLib.GetMaxTemplateSize(mMaxTemplateSize)
        minBuffer = ByteArray(mMaxTemplateSize[0])
        jsgfpLib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ANSI378)
        jsgfpLib.GetImageQuality(
            mImageWidth.toLong(),
            mImageHeight.toLong(),
            mRegisterImage,
            quality1
        )
        var fpInfo: SGFingerInfo? = SGFingerInfo()
        fpInfo?.FingerNumber = 1
        fpInfo?.ImageQuality = quality1[0]
        fpInfo?.ImpressionType = SGImpressionType.SG_IMPTYPE_LP
        fpInfo?.ViewNumber = 1
        jsgfpLib.CreateTemplate(fpInfo, mRegisterImage, minBuffer)
        val size = IntArray(1)
        jsgfpLib.GetTemplateSize(minBuffer, size)
        imgViewCapture.setImageBitmap(this.toGrayscale(mRegisterImage!!))

USB Permission Code
private val usbReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent?.action
        if (Const.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == action) {
            synchronized(this) {
                val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        Log.e("USB BroadcastReceiver VID", "" + device.vendorId)
                        Log.e("USB BroadcastReceiver VID", "" + device.productId)
                    } else {
                        Log.e("TAG", "mUsbReceiver.onReceive() Device is null")
                    }
                } else
                    Log.e(
                        "TAG",
                        "mUsbReceiver.onReceive() permission denied for device $device"
                    )
            }
        }
    }

SecuGen permission
var errorValue = jsgfpLib.Init(SGFDxDeviceName.SG_DEV_AUTO)
    if (errorValue != SGFDxErrorCode.SGFDX_ERROR_NONE) {
        if (secuGenDialog == 1) {
            val dlgAlert = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            if (errorValue == SGFDxErrorCode.SGFDX_ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
                dlgAlert.setMessage("The attached fingerprint device is not supported on Android")
            } else {

                fingerPageVisibilityGone()
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Fingerprint device initialization failed!")
            }
            dlgAlert.setTitle("SecuGen Fingerprint SDK")
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(false)
            // dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { _: DialogInterface?, _: Int -> requireActivity().finish() }
            dlgAlert.create().show()
        }
    } else {
        val usbDevice = jsgfpLib.GetUsbDevice()
        if (usbDevice == null) {
            if (secuGenDialog == 1) {
                fingerPageVisibilityGone()
                val dlgAlert = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                dlgAlert.setMessage("SecuGen fingerprint sensor not found!")
                dlgAlert.setTitle("SecuGen Fingerprint SDK")
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false)
                dlgAlert.create().show()
            }
        } else {
           
            var hasPermission = jsgfpLib.GetUsbManager().hasPermission(usbDevice)
            if (!hasPermission) {
                if (!usbPermissionRequested) {
                    usbPermissionRequested = true
                    jsgfpLib.GetUsbManager().requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent)
                } else {
                    //wait up to 20 seconds for the system to grant USB permission

                    hasPermission = jsgfpLib.GetUsbManager().hasPermission(usbDevice)
                    var i = 0
                    while (!hasPermission && i <= 40) {
                        ++i
                        hasPermission = jsgfpLib.GetUsbManager().hasPermission(usbDevice)
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500)
                        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hasPermission) {
                errorValue = jsgfpLib.OpenDevice(0)
                if (errorValue == SGFDxErrorCode.SGFDX_ERROR_NONE) {
                    bSecuGenDeviceOpened = true
                    val deviceInfo = SGDeviceInfoParam()
                    jsgfpLib.GetDeviceInfo(deviceInfo)
                    mImageWidth = deviceInfo.imageWidth
                    mImageHeight = deviceInfo.imageHeight
                    mImageDPI = deviceInfo.imageDPI
                    jsgfpLib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ANSI378)
                    jsgfpLib.GetMaxTemplateSize(mMaxTemplateSize)
                    
                    autoOn.start()
                }
            }
        }
    }

But I am getting crash from other device Like Realme, mi, Techno, Oneplus etc.
Crash occur and give me a message Null Pointer Exception.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long SecuGen.Driver.SmartCapture3Fdu05.Start(int, boolean)' on a null object reference

I attach an image of my code. I am getting crash in the result line.
I do not find any solution.
Please help me.
[enter image description here][1]
I tried the given image code. But it's return null and app is crash. I setup the SDK properly. But for few device (such as: Oneplus, Realme, mi, Techno, etc) i am getting the null.
I need the suggestion where is code error. How can i solve this problem .


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. 2) You don't provide details on which library you are using and how you added the library to your Android project.


I download SecuGen SDK from there web site for android. I set up the SDK according to their guide line. I got the finger print image Only for samsung android device. But i don't get finger Print image from other android device(Such as: One Plus, Realme, Xiaomi etc).
`mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
sgfplib = new JSGFPLib(this, (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
byte[] buffer = new byte[mImageWidth*mImageHeight];
long result = sgfplib.GetImage(buffer); `

@MorrisonChang I am getting error from result value. its return null except Samsung android handset.

Please edit your post to include any additional information rather than comments, which devices worked and didn't work and if any sample/testing app included in the SDK behave the same or different than your code.

@MorrisonChang I updated my post. I get error from var result = jsgfpLib.GetImage(mRegisterImage)  into Image capture code section

You will likely want to include the entire stack trace here.

I solved it. I just configure on SDK level. Its working fine. - Thanks all for your support
